# How do you perform an excellent throw?

Tags: pokemon-go

Sometimes I get an excellent throw when catching a Pokemon. What did I do? Did I hit the Pokemon on the head or is because of the catching circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get "Nice", "Great", or "Excellent" for hitting inside the smaller circle (The one which changes size). If you hit it in the exact center of this smaller circle you will get "Excellent".

[**Source**](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4rp1dp/excellent_throw_help/)